# Post Data in XML To Server By HTML Form

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml, jquery

Hello I am facing problem while integrating a payment gateway, gateway needs the request in XML format, my site and cart is in PHP, I want a solution to post my HTML form values to server in XML format, server needs the following XML format:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST" action="https://3ds.cps.lv/GatorServo/request">
    <input name="type" value="sendForAuth">
    <textarea name="xml">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <cpsxml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.cps.lv/xml/ns/cpsxml
        https://3ds.cps.lv/GatorServo/Gator_SendForAuth.xsd"
        xmlns="http://www.cps.lv/xml/ns/cpsxml">
    <header xmlns="">
    <responsetype>direct</responsetype>
    <user>test_sign</user>
    <type>sendForAuth</type>
    <transType>DB</transType>
    <digiSignature>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</digiSignature>
    </header>
    <request xmlns="">
    <orderNumber>012345</orderNumber>
    <cardholder>
      <firstName>FirstName</firstName>
      <lastName>LastName</lastName>
      <street>Street</street>
      <zip>54321</zip>
      <city>City</city>
      <country>LV</country>
      <email>email@domain.com</email>
      <ip>123.124.125.126</ip>
    </cardholder>
    <amount>
      <value>1000</value>
      <currency>USD</currency>
    </amount>
    <product>
      <productName>Product Name</productName>
      <productUrl>www.test.com</productUrl>
    </product>
  </request> 
</cpsxml>
</textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="Send">
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP File, I have tried using json2xml but no luck so far

```
<?php

require_once('../assist/cart-load.php');

if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['assist'])){
$order_id= $_REQUEST['order_id'];
$a_amount = $_REQUEST['a_total'];
$c_amount = $_REQUEST['c_total'];
$admin_curr = $_REQUEST['a_curr'];
$chk_curr = $_REQUEST['c_curr'];

$checksum = $_SESSION['basket']['security'];

$checksum2 = $_SESSION['basket']['security2'];
}
?>

      <html>
     <head><title>Complete Your Payment</title>
     <script src="json2xml.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var formjson = $('form#payment_form').serializeArray();
//var formxml = $.compactJSON(mjson);
var formxml = json2xml(formjson);
alert(formxml);
$.post("/collect.cgi", { 'data': formxml }, function (data){ });
     </script>
     </head>
   <body>
    <form method="post" id="payment_form" name="payment_form"  action="https://3ds.cps.lv/GatorServo/request">
    <input type="hidden" name="responsetype" value="direct">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="test_pasta_sign">
    <input name="type" type="hidden" value="sendForAuth">
    <input type="hidden" name="transType" value="DB">
    <input type="hidden" name="digisignature" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
    <p>Order Number</p>
    <input type="text" readonly name="orderNumber" value="<?php echo $order_id; ?>">
    <p>F Name</p>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
    <p>L Name</p>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
    <p>Street Address</p>
    <input type="text" name="street" value="">
    <p>Zip</p>
    <input type="text" name="zip" value="">
    <p>City</p>
    <input type="text" name="city" value="">
    <p>Country</p>
    <input type="text" name="country" value="">
    <p>Email</p>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="email@domain.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="123.124.125.126">
    <p>Enter Card No.</p>
    <input type="text" name="cardNumber" value="">
    <p>Enter CVV</p>
    <input type="text" name="cvv" value="">
    <p>Card Expiry</p>
    <input type="text" name="expires" value="">
    <p>Amount</p>
    <input type="text" name="value" readonly value="<?php echo $a_amount; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD">
    <p>Product Name</p>
    <input type="text" name="productName" value="Product Name" readonly>
    <input type="hidden" name="productUrl" value="http://www.test.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form></body></html>
```

Kindly provide me a better solution for this problem. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I have now removed the jsontoxml and now using jquery.ajax, here is the script

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var ajaxurl="https://3ds.cps.lv/GatorServo/request";
var str="";

for(i=0; i<document.payment_form.elements.length; i++)
{
   var fieldName = document.payment_form.elements[i].name;
   var fieldValue = document.payment_form.elements[i].value;
   str += "<" + fieldName + ">" ;
    str += fieldValue ;
   str += "</" + fieldName + ">" ;
}

$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: str, 
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success : parse_result,
    error : show_error
}); 

function parse_result(xml){
    //
}
function show_error(){
    //
}
     </script>
```

But now am getting error: "Malformed XML Request" from the server.

Any solution?

Comment: What were the results of using `json2xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your XML output into notepad, save it as an XML file and then try to open that XML file in a web browser locally. The web browser will try to parse the XML and tell you what problem(s) it is having. You should be able to narrow down your XML formatting issues from there.